# How to fix conflict css style

Tags: html, css

I tried to use this css on the circular menu, but the css I use conflicts with main css. Conflict mainly on style `position: relative`.

Here's the code below. I need `position relative`, but other css in main website conflicts.

```css
* {
  position: relative;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.cn-button {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 11;
  margin-left: -2.25em;
  bottom: 2em;
  width: 4.5em;
  height: 4.5em;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: none;
  background-color: #0dbfb5;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px 1px rgba(76, 95, 95, 0.54);
  text-transform: capitalize;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -7em;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-top: -13em;
  margin-left: -13.5em;
  width: 27em;
  height: 27em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease 0.3s;
  transition: all .3s ease 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
  transform: scale(0.1);
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button class="cn-button" id="cn-button">+</button>
<div class="cn-wrapper" id="cn-wrapper">
   <ul>
       <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-picture"></span></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-headphones"></span></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-home"></span></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-facetime-video"></span></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-envelope-alt"></span></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div id="cn-overlay" class="cn-overlay"></div>
```

What should I do?

Comment: why are you using * in your css?

Comment: Why would you set every element in your document to position relative?

Comment: this is default plugin circula menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all try to merger the css changes and only keep css properties which you need (properties that need to be changed). Then use !important tag for those properties that you need or you can keep your css and add !important tag to position property.

This is not the right way to do but it is a fix.